# how to get row index in createeditor function

Tags: javascript, jqwidget

i want row details for what i clicked,actually am using create editor for assigning dropdownlist in grid column i got it correctly but am not getting the row details properly every row giving same values so how can i get correct row details

i used this code

```
{
       text: 'Sort Type', dataField: 'aliasname1', columntype: 'dropdownlist', width: '11%', editable: true,

       createeditor: function (row, cellvalue, editor) {                

           var colvalue = $('#shipmentgrid').jqxGrid('getcellvalue', row, 'column');
           var tblvalue = $('#shipmentgrid').jqxGrid('getcellvalue', row, 'table');
           // construct the editor.   
           var requiredfield = ["Ascending", "Descending", "Unsorted"];
           editor.jqxDropDownList({ source: requiredfield, dropDownHeight: '80px', autoDropDownHeight: 0, selectedIndex:-1, checkboxes: true })
       }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The row's index is passed as parameter - function(row, ....
If you want to get the row's data based on that index you may use getrowdata method and pass the row's index as param.